# Promise.all(...).spread is not a function when running promises in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I'm trying to run 2 promises in paralel with sequelize, and then render the results in a .ejs template, but I'm receiving this error:

```
 Promise.all(...).spread is not a function
```

This is my code:

```
var environment_hash = req.session.passport.user.environment_hash;
var Template  = require('../models/index').Template;
var List      = require('../models/index').List;

var values = { 
    where: { environment_hash: environment_hash,
             is_deleted: 0 
        }                    
};

template = Template.findAll(values);
list = List.findAll(values);


Promise.all([template,list]).spread(function(templates,lists) {

    res.render('campaign/create.ejs', {
        templates: templates,
        lists: lists
    });

});
```

How can I solve thhis?

Comment: `.spread()` is not a standard promise method.  It is available in the Bluebird promise library - are you using that?  Your code you included does not show that.  You can also just use `.then(results => {...})` and access the results as `results[0]` and `results[1]`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I imported BlueBird and it's working now.

Comment: **`"I'm trying to run 2 promises in parallel".`** No you are not because you cannot as JS is single threaded. What you are dealing with is that you don't know which promise will end first.

Comment: @ankitbug94, but it still can be parallel IO operations.

Comment: @vp_arth so what? promises are neither going to start at same time nor end at same time and OP mentioned **promise**

Comment: Based on my prior comment, I posted an answer that offers you three different solutions.  The most elegant of which is to use destructing to remove the need for `.spread()` entirely, though I still recommend Bluebird for these reasons: [Are there still reasons to use promise libraries like Q or BlueBird now that we have ES6 promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960886/are-there-still-reasons-to-use-promise-libraries-like-q-or-bluebird-now-that-we/34961040#34961040)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'll make my comment into an answer since it solved your issue.

`.spread()` is not a standard promise method.  It is available in the Bluebird promise library.  Your code you included does not show that.  Three possible solutions:

**Access array values directly**

You can just use `.then(results => {...})` and access the results as `results[0]` and `results[1]`.

**Include the Bluebird Promise library**

You can include the Bluebird promise library so you have access to `.spread()`.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
```

**Use destructuring in the callback arguments**

In the latest versions of nodejs, you could also use destructuring of parameters which kind of removes the need for `.spread()` like this:

```
Promise.all([template,list]).then(function([templates,lists]) {
    res.render('campaign/create.ejs', {templates, lists});
});
```

Comment: +1 [destructuring](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) assignment , or maybe better to call it "destructuring to parameters"

Comment: Yes, with ES6 we don't need Bluebird spread in most scenarios. We can achieve what it does by just destructuring using then callback.

Answer (score 20):

You can write it without non-standard `Bluebird` features and keep less dependencies as well.

```
Promise.all([template,list])
  .then(function([templates,lists]) {
  };
```

[ES6 Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
Promise.all([
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.resolve(2),
]).then(([one, two]) => console.log(one, two));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `Bluebird` Promise feature and you can access it via `Sequelize.Promise` without installing `Bluebird` module itself

```
Sequelize.Promise.all(promises).spread(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install BlueBird.

```
npm install bluebird
```

Then:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
```

Comment: Much better is not to use these specific API. ES6 has so much features for spreading..