# Don't we need something better than Promise.all?

Tags: async-await, es6-promise

Here is my pretty code using await/async

```
monthlyBuckets(req, res) {
  const monthlyBuckets = []
  const now = DateTime.local()
  let date = config.beginningOfTime
  while (date < now) {
    monthlyBuckets.push({
      epoch: date.toMillis(),
      month: date.month,
      year: date.year,
      actions: await redis.get(`actions_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
      interested: await redis.scard(`sinterested_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
      adventurous: await redis.scard(`sadventurous_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
      active: await redis.scard(`sactive_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
    })
    date = date.plus({month: 1})
  }
  res.status(200).json(monthlyBuckets)
}
```

I like it, but making so many requests not in parallel leads to a request time close to 3 sec.

So, here is my ugly solution without async/await, just promises:

```
monthlyBuckets(req, res) {
    const monthlyBuckets = []
    const actions = []
    const interested = []
    const adventurous = []
    const active = []
    const now = DateTime.local()
    let date = config.beginningOfTime
    let entryCount = 0
    while (date < now) {
      monthlyBuckets.push({
        epoch: date.toMillis(),
        month: date.month,
        year: date.year,
      })
      actions.push(redis.get(`actions_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`))
      interested.push(redis.scard(`sinterested_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`))
      adventurous.push(redis.scard(`sadventurous_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`))
      active.push(redis.scard(`sactive_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`))
      date = date.plus({month: 1})
      entryCount++
    }
    const data = await Promise.all(actions.concat(interested).concat(adventurous).concat(active))
    for (let i = 0; i < entryCount; i++) {
      monthlyBuckets[i].actions = data[i]
      monthlyBuckets[i].interested = data[entryCount + i]
      monthlyBuckets[i].adventurous = data[entryCount * 2 + i]
      monthlyBuckets[i].active = data[entryCount * 3 + i]
    }
    res.status(200).json(monthlyBuckets)
  }
}
```

That ain't pretty, but it gets the job done under 200ms

Can I have pretty and efficient?

Comment: You can use `await Promise.all(...)` just fine.

Comment: That makes it 2% less ugly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the code above is that you are trying to:

1. use **one Promise.all()** for all the promises
2. process the output of all the responses in **one callback**

Though this is not a mistake, it can lead to hard to "read" code.

The code could be written as:

```
while (date < now) {
  let dateData = {
    epoch: date.toMillis(),
    month: date.month,
    year: date.year,
  };
  let promiseData = Promise.all([
      dateData, // dataData is cast(made to) automatically into a promise
      redis.get(`actions_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
      redis.scard(`sinterested_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
      redis.scard(`sadventurous_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
      redis.scard(`sactive_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`)
  ]).then([data, actions, interested, adventurous, active] => {
      // process the data here for each month
      data.actions = actions;
      data.interested = interested;
      data.adventurous = adventurous;
      data.active = active;
      return data;
});
  monthlyBuckets.push(promiseData);
  date = date.plus({month: 1});
}

const data = await Promise.all(monthlyBuckets);
res.status(200).json(data);
```

What changed is

- **Grouping the promises** for each month
- Processing a month `s **group of promises, not all the promises together** and returning the data as wanted.

There is nothing wrong with grouping promises eg:

```
Promise.all([
       Promise.all([ ...]),
       Promise.all([ ...]),
       singlePromise,
       ...
]);
```

processing promises eg:

```
promiseProcessed1 = promise1.then(callback1);
promiseProcessed12 = Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(callback2);
```

or reusing promises eg:

```
promiseProcessed1 = promise1.then(callback1);
promiseProcessed12 = Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(callback2);
resultDatapromise = Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promiseProcessed1, promiseProcessed12]).then(callback2);
```

**References**

- [Reuse promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain/28250704#28250704)
- [ES6 Destructuring assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750392/4448410)

Comment: This is slightly easier to read. But will run slower, it is not retrieving the data for the next month until the previous month has been processed, but there is no real reason to do so. The array argument returned in Promise.all().then is not on par with the general esthetic of ES6 syntax. That is what prompted this question. I think ES6 promises is a good start, but I realize it has a lot to be improved upon.

Comment: It will not run slower and "not retrieving the data for the next month until the previous month has been processed" is not true. As for "general esthetic of ES6 syntax", maybe you can use "destructuring in the callback arguments": eg like in the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750254/promise-all-spread-is-not-a-function-when-running-promises-in-parallel

Comment: That's right, there is no await in your code. Yes could probably write ...then([actions, interested, adventurous, active] => ({actions, interested, adventurous, active})) to avoid indexed arrays

Comment: `const data = await Promise.all(monthlyBuckets);` this line is superfluous

Comment: @JonathanR thanks for pointing this out, you are right. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Taking apart different steps could help in this situation. Example:

```
function createBucket(date, ops){
    const b = {
        epoch: date.toMillis(),
        month: date.month,
        year: date.year,
        actions: redis.get(`actions_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
        interested: redis.scard(`sinterested_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
        adventurous: redis.scard(`sadventurous_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
        active: redis.scard(`sactive_monthly_${date.year}_${date.month}`),
    }

    const promised = ['actions','interested', 'adventurous', 'active'];
    promised.forEach(p => ops.push(async () => {b[p] = await b[p]}));
}

async function monthlyBuckets(req,res){
    const monthlyBuckets = []
    const now = DateTime.local()
    let date = config.beginningOfTime

    const ops = [];
    while (date < now) {
      monthlyBuckets.push(createBucket(date,ops));
      date = date.plus({month: 1})
    }

    await Promise.all(ops);
    res.status(200).json(monthlyBuckets)
}
```